# Passing an array/pointer into a stuct in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc

I have a function in c declared as so:

```
void SendMsg(TXMsg_t *TXMsg);
```

This is the struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t DestAddr;
    uint16_t PayloadLength;
    uint8_t Payload[512];
} TXMsg_t;
```

I can manually stuff `TXMsg.Payload`, call `SendMsg(&TXMsg);`,  and it works fine.  But in one case I have a intermediary function calling SendMsg:

```
void main(void)
{
    uint16_t Addr = 0x1234;
    uint16_t TXLength = 0x0004;
    uint8_t TXData[4] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD};

    MiddleFunction(Addr, TXLength, TXData);
}

void MiddleFunction(uint16_t Addr, uint16_t TXLength, uint8_t *TXData);
{
    TXMsg_t TXMsg;

    TXMsg.DestAddr = Addr;
    TXMsg.PayloadLength = TXLength;
    TXMsg.Payload = TXData;        // This is the problem!!!

    SendMsg(&TXMsg);
}
```

This gives me an error: "assignment to expression with array type".

My goal is to simply take the **pointer** to TXData and pass it along to my SendMsg function.  This is an embedded app and I don't want to take the time or the memory to actually copy the data...

How can I do this?

Comment: `memcpy(TXMsg.Payload, TXData, TXLength);` instead of `TXMsg.Payload = TXData;`

Comment: Thanks @BLUEPIXY, I edited the question to say that I am trying to avoid actually copying the data :)

Comment: You cannot avoid copying the data without changing the definition of type `TXMsg_t`.  C does not permit an array to be the left-hand operand of an assignment.  Even if it did, the semantics would need to be to copy the data.  Do not be confused: though arrays and pointers are closely related in C, they are not at all the same thing.

Comment: @bitsmack Change `uint8_t Payload[512];` to `uint8_t *Payload;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `memcpy` to copy the bytes from one array to the other.  You also need to pass in the size of the `TXData` array in `MiddleFunction`:

```
int main(void)   // main must return int
{
    uint16_t Addr = 0x1234;
    uint16_t TXLength = 0x0004;
    uint8_t TXData[4] = {0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD};

    MiddleFunction(Addr, TXLength, TXData, sizeof(TXData));
}

void MiddleFunction(uint16_t Addr, uint16_t TXLength, uint8_t *TXData, int dataLen)
{
    TXMsg_t TXMsg;

    TXMsg.DestAddr = Addr;
    TXMsg.PayloadLength = TXLength;
    memset(TXMsg.Payload, 0, sizeof(TXMsg.Payload));   // zero out the array to start
    memcpy(TXMsg.Payload, TXData, dataLen);            // copy the bytes from the source array

    SendMsg(&TXMsg);
}
```

EDIT:

If you don't want to copy the data, you need to redefine the struct so that `Payload` is a pointer instead of a fixed array.  So you would change this:

```
uint8_t Payload[512];
```

To this:

```
uint8_t *Payload;
```

Then you can use the rest of your code as is (your struct already contains a length field, so you don't need to pass in extra data as I originally thought).

Comment: Excellent, your edit is just what I was looking for :)